# Alias naming the same table used to self compare inside query (ORACLE DB)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a clients table and I'm writing a query to see which clients share the same phone number. 
The structure and the query :

```sql
CREATE TABLE Client
(noClient       INTEGER         NOT NULL,
 nameClient     VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 noTelephone    VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (noClient)
);
```

```sql
SELECT c.nameClient, c2.nameClient2
FROM Client c NATURAL JOIN Client c2(noClient2, nameClient2, noTelephone) 
WHERE c.nomClient < c2.nomClient
```

The problem here is I keep getting an error

```sql
FROM Client c NATURAL JOIN Client c2(noClient2, nameClient2, noTelephone)
                                    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL Command not properly ended
```

Is there a proper way to rename the table AND its columns?

I have a solution around that but i'd like to know the proper syntax of making an alias of a table (and it's columns) inside the query.
And also of course if there are better ways to approach when using the same table to compare it's values

The workaround is to force the join on the `noTelephone` without renaming the columns :

```sql
SELECT c.nameClient, c2.nameClient
FROM Client c JOIN Client c2 ON c.noTelephone = c2.noTelephone
WHERE c.nameClient < c2.nameClient
```

Comment: Oracle probably doesn't support that form.  But you can use a `WITH` clause: `WITH cte (new1, new2, new3) AS (SELECT old1, old2, old3 FROM tablename) ...` or a derived table.  Question: Why do you want to do that? It's not really necessary.  Just provide the table alias (correlation name) and use the same column names, as you did in the second query.

Comment: What is the purpose of natural join except ambiguity in case of future changes in source tables' structure? Use explicit join and column names with table alias, this will help you to understand the idea of the query after some years passed.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables doesn't have foreign key constraints the `NATURAL JOIN` clause won't work.

BTW please avoid using NATURAL JOIN, use explicit `JOIN` has explained here:
https://rules.sonarsource.com/plsql/RSPEC-2521